# OpenCV VideoCapture class takes long time to open camera connected with dvr

Tags: java, opencv, video

I used the following code

```
    VideoCapture videoCapture[]=new Videocapture[4];

    for(int i=0;i<4,i++)
    {
      videoCapture[i]=new VideoCapture();
                        videoCapture[i].open("http://192.168.1.7:80/cgi-bin/view.cgi?chn="+i+"&u=admin&p=");
                        if(videoCapture[i].isOpened()){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jfrmMsg, "connected");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jfrmMsg, "not connected");
                        }

}
```

Here it will take too much time to open camera. **connected** message is displayed after every 3-4 minutes. I want to read camera as quickly as posible. Can any one tell me how should we do this.

Comment: "*takes logn time*" Do you mean `log(n)` or "long"?

Comment: is it faster using VLC or something?

Comment: yes it is faster using vlc. But in my code it will take too much time

Answer (score 0):

Change `video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to `video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`